# GPU unavailable tensorflow in jupyter notebook using ubuntu

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, anaconda, jupyter

I have gone through a very long process of installing tensorflow 2.12 along with anaconda, NVIDIA drivers, CUDA, and cuDNN. Yesterday, my jupyter notebook script showed that I had a GPU available, however, it is not showing available anymore.

I am running this on a Linux (Ubuntu) terminal. I installed the terminal using wsl --install. Then, I went through and installed the latest python, anaconda, and jupyter notebook. From there, I went through the Linux installation of tensorflow found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip.

To check if GPU is available, I've been using:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(len(tf.config.lift_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

It should return a length greater than 0 if GPU is available and it was returning 1. After running a few simple models, it is now return 0 again.

I've tried restarting my kernel and uninstalling and reinstalling python, tensorflow, and anaconda. I've also tried updating CUDA/cuDNN/NVIDIA drivers. I was thinking maybe the GPU is not available because I already trained a model and that the GPU is now reserved for that script.

I also think that there is something wrong with the paths or something. I conda installed everything except for the jupyter notebook, which I pip installed. I saw that when I conda installed jupyter I had to go through the anaconda thing to open notebook but if I pip installed jupyter then I could just type `jupyter notebook` in my ubuntu terminal and I can easily open notebook in chrome.

I've also tried installing tensorflow-gpu but I guess something is wrong with that and it has never worked for me.

Update:
I have uninstalled Ubuntu, reinstalled it, installed anaconda, installed tensorflow, and got it to to show my GPU. At this point, I restarted my computer and now tensorflow is not showing an available GPU.

Steps taken:
[image]

Comment: Have you considered installing a real Linux setup using dual-boot, instead of the WSL hack?

Comment: Company computer and I can't dual boot it. I eventually found an answer. I guess I had to permanently add the path.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, the Tensorflow install guide temporarily sets the nvidia driver path. Setting the path is required each time the Ubuntu is restarted.

I fixed this by following the steps provided in my update earlier. Afterwards I opened an Ubuntu terminal and ran a `nano ~/.bashrc`, scrolled to the bottom and added the CUDNN_PATH, export and python3 to the end of this file.

[image]