# Jupyter kernel dies in Ubuntu when predicting in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, anaconda

I just installed a Linux subsystem on my windows and was able to verify that I can connect to my GPU in tensorflow (see my question here: [GPU unavailable tensorflow in jupyter notebook using ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867553/gpu-unavailable-tensorflow-in-jupyter-notebook-using-ubuntu)). I tried to run a GANs model but whenever I get to the prediction of new images, my jupyter kernel dies (I provided the terminal output below).

I am running tensorflow v2.12.0 and Cuda 11.3.58

```
2023-03-29 10:40:36.194790: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-03-29 10:40:36.690448: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2023-03-29 10:40:37.609649: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-03-29 10:40:37.625212: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-03-29 10:40:37.625255: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-03-29 10:40:37.626900: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-03-29 10:40:37.626949: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-03-29 10:40:37.626979: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-03-29 10:40:38.273806: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-03-29 10:40:38.274180: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-03-29 10:40:38.274215: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1722] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU id 0, defaulting to 0.  Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2023-03-29 10:40:38.274403: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-03-29 10:40:38.274534: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1635] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2042 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Quadro T2000, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
2023-03-29 10:40:40.439728: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:424] Loaded cuDNN version 8600
Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8. Error: libcuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[I 10:40:43.009 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
WARNING:root:kernel a03feebf-dd7a-41b4-9a9f-0333c160f338 restarted
```

I've tried uninstalling tensorflow and reinstalling it. I used anaconda to install everything and I am not quite sure how anaconda works. So I am pretty sure there is a path messed up somewhere. Also, I am not an developer so feel free to talk to me like I'm 5 or I won't understand lol.

Answer (score 1):

`CUDA 11.3.58` is not compatible with `TensorFlow 2.12.0`. Please check this [tested build config](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux).

Please install `CUDA 11.8` and `CuDNN 8.6` which is compatible with `TensorFlow version 2.12`. Also re-verify that you have followed all the steps by steps instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) correctly to enable GPU support in your system.